# PHP extract 1 or more value from array_filter

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry this must me simple but I am terrible on arrays.

I need to extract $d1,$d2,$d3,$d4,$d5,$d6 from 
array_filter($d1,$d2,$d3,$d4,$d5,$d6)

Example

```
$pieces = array_filter([$d1,$d2,$d3,$d4,$d5,$d6]);

if(count(array_filter($pieces)) == 2){ echo $d1.' '.$d2 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need the array in a variable:
(not sure on your context but is 'array_filter' needed at all?

```
$myArray = array($d1, $d2, $d3, $d4, $d5, $d6);
```

Then when echoing $d1.' '.$d2 for example:

```
echo $myArray[0] . ' ' . $myArray[1];
```

**Update**

So to more accurately answer your question, I'm assuming you want to echo all array items, use a for loop:

```
$output;
for ($i = 0; $i< count($pieces); $i++){
    output .= $pieces[$i] . ' ';
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: I need array_filter to avoid empty values, Thanks JW

Comment: You've called `array_filter` twice, I'm fairly confident you don't need to call it again in your if statement, as the first call will remove empty values from `$pieces`

Comment: Sorry I need separated vars and they must not be empty. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are on right track. Try below soltuion:

```
$array = array('test1','test2','','test4','','','','testx');

//remove empty values
$filterd_array = array_filter($array);

//implode with space and print
echo implode(' ', $filterd_array);
```

output:

```
test1 test2 test4 testx
```